# Laptops on wireless network can's see each other (ping, rdp, net use, etc)

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, connection, intranet

Asus RT-N66U set up as Router using WPA2-Personal
All clients (laptops) connect using 2.4 GHz to same wireless SSID (all 255.255.255.0 subnet)

Problem: *None* of the laptops (all Windows) on my home intranet can ping each other, either by name or by IP.  *All* of them have no problems whatsoever accessing the internet (web)!

Old router (Linksys WRT-54G) did not have these issues.  Laptop settings unchanged.

What Am I doing wrong?

(Interesting note: In windows under "Wireless Network Properties", the computers show "Network Type: Access Point" - I've confirmed that RT-N66U is configured as router).

Comment: See if this helps, at least for ping. If it does it could very well be Windows Firewall blocking things by default: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-enable-ping-response-in-windows-7/5aff5f8d-f138-4c9a-8646-5b3a99f1cae6

Comment: also, some wirless router have option for preventing wifi hosts from talking to each other, check the router configuration to disable this option if it exists.

Comment: Are you using Windows on the RT-N66U?

Comment: Solved!  My household is heavily into volunteer work using the web, so it wasn't until now that I could reboot the router.  I don't know what was wrong, but all problems are now gone... (1) couldn't see other computers on intranet, (2) one computer couldn't see internet (first seen today), (3) web speed tested at < 10 mbps (now 35, as it should be).     I'm amazed that these diverse problems could be solved bby simply rebooting the router.  Thanks for all that responded